# Cleanest way to cache function results in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, caching

I have quite a heavy function in MATLAB:

```
function [out] = f ( in1, in2, in3)
```

Which is called quite often with the same parameters.
The function is deterministic so for given input parameters its output will always be the same.

What would be the simplest way of storing the results of computed inputs in the function such that if the function will be called again with the same output it would be able to answer quickly?

Is a persistent variable which maps (using `containers.Map` or some other class) input set `<in1, in2, in3>` to a result the way to go?

Note that any method which requires saving the data to disk is out of the question in my application.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284130/caching-matlab-function-results-to-file

Comment: I saw that (and suggested it in the question), but the problem is I can't find a reasonable way of hashing the 3 input arguments so it'd fit that class.

Comment: what type are your three inputs? are they scalars? vector? matrices? what is their normal range of values? how many values do you expect to cache?

Comment: @Shai-
The three inputs are multidimensional matrices and so is the output. Almost all values are either 0 or 1, although some may be in (0,1).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - what you are after is called 'Memoization'. Google *matlab memoization*, and you will find some useful results. Some samples (didn't check code validity): - [Loren Shure on memoization](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/02/08/use-nested-functions-to-memoize-costly-functions/) - [A matlab method on Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33068-a-multidimensional-map-class/content/memoize.m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MATLAB now ships with a function just for this purpose.
The technique used is called "memoization" and the function's name is "memoize".

Check out : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memoize.html

Comment: Nice catch, this is a new feature in R2017a. This should be _the_ answer now.

Comment: [New and improved memoize blog post from Loren!](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2018/07/05/memoize-functions-in-matlab/)

Answer (score 7):

Below is an idea for a CacheableFunction class

- It seems all of the answers to your main question are pointing the same direction - a persistent Map is the consensus way to cache results, and I do this too.
- If the inputs are arrays, they'll need to be hashed to a string or scalar to be used as a map key.  There are a lot of ways to hash your 3 input arrays to a key, I used [DataHash](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) in my solution below.
- I chose to make it a class rather than a function like memoize so that the input hashing function can be dynamically specified one time, rather than hardcoded.
- Depending on the form of your output, it also uses [dzip/dunzip](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8899-rapid-lossless-data-compression-of-numerical-or-string-variables) to reduce the footprint of the saved outputs.
- Potential improvement: a clever way of deciding which elements to remove from the persistent map when its memory footprint approaches some limit.

Class definition

```
classdef CacheableFunction < handle
    properties
        exeFun
        hashFun
        cacheMap
        nOutputs
        zipOutput
    end

    methods
        function obj = CacheableFunction(exeFun, hashFun, nOutputs)
            obj.exeFun = exeFun;
            obj.hashFun = hashFun;
            obj.cacheMap = containers.Map;
            obj.nOutputs = nOutputs;
            obj.zipOutput = [];
        end

        function [result] = evaluate(obj, varargin)

            thisKey = obj.hashFun(varargin);

            if isKey(obj.cacheMap, thisKey)
                if obj.zipOutput
                    result = cellfun(@(x) dunzip(x), obj.cacheMap(thisKey), 'UniformOutput', false);
                else
                    result = obj.cacheMap(thisKey);
                end
            else
                [result{1:obj.nOutputs}] = obj.exeFun(varargin);

                if isempty(obj.zipOutput)
                    obj.zipCheck(result);
                end

                if obj.zipOutput
                    obj.cacheMap(thisKey) = cellfun(@(x) dzip(x), result, 'UniformOutput', false);
                else
                    obj.cacheMap(thisKey) = result;
                end
            end
        end


        function [] = zipCheck(obj,C)
            obj.zipOutput = all(cellfun(@(x) isreal(x) & ~issparse(x) & any(strcmpi(class(x), ...
                {'double','single','logical','char','int8','uint8',...
                 'int16','uint16','int32','uint32','int64','uint64'})), C));
        end

    end
end
```

Testing it out...

```
function [] = test_caching_perf()

A = CacheableFunction(@(x) long_annoying_function(x{:}), @(x) DataHash(x), 3);

B = rand(50, 50);
C = rand(50, 50);
D = rand(50, 50);

tic;
myOutput = A.evaluate(B, C, D);
toc

tic;
myOutput2 = A.evaluate(B, C, D);
toc

cellfun(@(x, y) all(x(:) == y(:)), myOutput, myOutput2)

end

function [A, B, C] = long_annoying_function(A, B, C)

    for ii = 1:5000000
        A = A+1;
        B = B+2;
        C = C+3;
    end
end
```

And results

```
>> test_caching_perf
Elapsed time is 16.781889 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.011116 seconds.
ans =
    1     1     1
```

Comment: The naming conventions you picked are a bit clunky and the description at the beginning a bit thick, otherwise this answer would get more deserved attention.

Answer (score 5):

Persistent map is indeed a nice way to implement cached results. Advantages I can think of:

- No need to implement hash function for every data type.
- Matlab matrices are copy-on-write, which can offer certain memory efficiency.
- If memory usage is an issue, one can control how many results to cache.

There is a file exchange submission, [A multidimensional map class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33068-a-multidimensional-map-class) by David Young, comes with a function memoize() does exactly this.  It's implementation uses a bit different mechanism (referenced local variable), but the idea is about the same.  Compared with persistent map inside each function, this memoize() function allows existing function to be memoized without modification. And as pointed out by Oleg, using DataHash (or equivalent) can further reduce the memory usage.

PS: I have used the MapN class extensively and it is quite reliable.  Actually I have submitted a bug report and the author fixed it promptly.

Comment: Adding DataHash to `memoize()` should reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: That is very good point and certainly true. The performance trade off is that the hash function will need to be evaluated on all inputs per call. I guess whether it'll be faster depends on the specific use case and performance of the hash function.