# MATLAB: Replacing multivariate function to avoid redundant calcs?

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I have a function F(x,y) of two variables (numerical inputs and outputs) which performs some fairly complex computations. My program calls this function sometimes hundreds of thousands of times over any individual run. However, it uses the same finite set of ordered pairs (x,y) during each run. So, I want to compute F on these pairs just once at the start of the program, and then store this input/output information for the remainder of the run.

I was originally thinking of using Matlab's containers.Map class. However, this does not allow for keys of the form [x, y] - each key must be a single number/string. So, I could just include all inputs/outputs in an Nx3 array and construct my own lookup function. I was wondering if there was any alternative which might be faster, or perhaps a way to utilize the containers.Map in this situation that I'm not seeing?

```
F = @(x,y) x + y;                      % Actual F is 100's of lines
inputs = [0 1; 0 2; 1 1; 1 2];         % Each row is (x,y) pair of only inputs I care about
z = F( inputs(:,1), inputs(:,2));      % Only outputs I care about
idealFunction = ?????                  % New function which only accepts (x,y) pairs above

idealFunction([0 2]);                  % Returns 2 by matching to element of z  
idealFunction([0 3]);                  % May throw an error but I don't care
                                       % since it's not in my inputs of interest
```

Comment: Please see: [mcve].

Comment: I'm not "asking a question about a problem caused by my code" and my question is also completely independent of the specific form of the function F, so I think not including code is the correct decision here.

Comment: If it's completely independent of the specific form of the function F then you should have no problem coming up with an example that illustrates what you're attempting to do, rather than a vague problem statement. Not including an example is not the correct decision.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "memoize", [which MATLAB includes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memoize.html)

Comment: An MCVE is not only crucial for debugging problems. Whenever you ask for help (free help!) you should make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Five lines of a minimal example of what you're trying to do can be understood in the fraction of the time it takes for us to read your wall of text. And possible answers will always be compatible if you give an actual example; all too often we see "*Oh yes, what I forgot to say was <arbitrary restriction that invalidates existing perfectly valid answers>.*"

Comment: Sorry I actually thought clouding my simple question with a trivial example would waste your time. Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163040/cleanest-way-to-cache-function-results-in-matlab). Don't let the accepted answer fool you; the new idiomatic (built-in) solution [is also there at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163040/cleanest-way-to-cache-function-results-in-matlab#comment89969913_26163040).

Comment: Thank you @excaza and Andras Deak. I had not heard of that function, and don't even have it in my current version of Matlab! I will upgrade ASAP. Cheers!