# How can I feed MATLAB's integral2 a vector of parameters via nested functions?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, vector

I want to calculate a 2D-integral for a vector of parameters in MATLAB. I know that integral2 has no 'ArrayValued' option. How can I rearrange the function handles to feed the integral a row vector `q` anyway? The 1D-integration works fine:

```
    clear all

    L=1000;
    R=80;

    formfactor = @(q,alpha) 2*sin(q.*cos(alpha)*L/2)./(q.*cos(alpha)*L/2).*besselj(1,q.*sin(alpha)*R)./(q.*sin(alpha)*R);
    result = @(q) integral(@(alpha) formfactor(q,alpha).^2.*sin(alpha),0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true);

    qbins = 100;
    q = logspace(-2,0,qbins);
    I = result(q);
```

Up to here the one-dimensional integration along `alpha` works. Now I multiply the integrand with a term `lattice_c` which depends additionally on `phi` and try to integrate again.

```
    a = 24;
    b = a*sqrt(3)/2;
    x=[-2.5*a, -2*a, -a, -a/2, a/2, a, 2*a, 2.5*a, 2*a, 2.5*a, 2*a, a, a/2, -a/2, -a, -2*a, -2.5*a, -2*a, -a, -a/2, a/2, a, a/2, -a/2 ];
    y=[b ,2*b ,2*b ,3*b ,3*b ,2*b ,2*b ,b ,0 ,-b ,-2*b ,-2*b ,-3*b ,-3*b ,-2*b ,-2*b ,-b ,0 ,0 ,b ,b ,0 ,-b ,-b ];

    lattice_a = @(q,position,alpha,phi) exp(sqrt(-1)*q*(x(position)*sin(alpha)*cos(phi) + y(position)*sin(alpha)*sin(phi)));
    lattice_b = @(q,alpha,phi) sum(lattice_a(q,:,alpha,phi));
    lattice_c = @(q,alpha,phi) formfactor(q,alpha).*lattice_b(q,alpha,phi);
    lattice_d = @(q) integral2(@(alpha,phi) lattice_c(q,alpha,phi).^2.*sin(alpha),0,pi/2,0,pi/3);

    Inew = lattice_d(q);

    figure()
    loglog(q,I)
```

The error message is "Error using  .* Matrix dimensions must agree." But technically, there are no matrices involved, since none of the parameters is array-valued anymore. What argument do I need to pass on differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But technically, there are no matrices involved

There are. The documentation of [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) specifies that the function being integrated

> must accept two arrays of the same size and return an array of corresponding values.  It must perform element-wise operations.

That is, integral2 passes some arrays of equal size as `alpha` and `phi` into your function `lattice_c`. This immediately breaks `sin(alpha)*cos(phi)` - you need `.*` there.

But that's not the end of story because you also want to multiply that by `x`. Your idea of introducing position argument and then passing `:` into it doesn't seem to help (at least in my R2013a, the effect of `:` as function argument is neither documented nor clear to me).

Without integration, you can check that `lattice_b(-1,0:1,0:1)` throws an error: the function cannot handle array arguments.

The underlying reason for most of these troubles is that you are stuffing too much logic into anonymous functions. Here is my rewrite: I split off `lattice_b`, folding `lattice_a` into it. Due to the presence of a non-anonymous function, I wrapped the top level code into function `main`.

Oh, and the entries of `q` should be dealt with one  at a time, for which a `for` loop is perfectly appropriate. There is no sense in trying to vectorize sophisticated operations such as evaluation of double integrals (I explained why [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30959662/3717023)).

```
function main()
clear all
L=1000;
R=80;
formfactor = @(q,alpha) 2*sin(q.*cos(alpha)*L/2)./(q.*cos(alpha)*L/2).*besselj(1,q.*sin(alpha)*R)./(q.*sin(alpha)*R);
result = @(q) integral(@(alpha) formfactor(q,alpha).^2.*sin(alpha),0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true);
lattice_c = @(q,alpha,phi) formfactor(q,alpha).*lattice_b(q,alpha,phi);
lattice_d = @(q) integral2(@(alpha,phi) lattice_c(q,alpha,phi).^2.*sin(alpha),0,pi/2,0,pi/3);

qbins = 100;
q = logspace(-2,0,qbins);
Inew = zeros(size(q));
for i=1:numel(q)
    Inew(i) = lattice_d(q(i));
end
disp(Inew)
end

function z = lattice_b(q,alpha,phi)
a = 24;
b = a*sqrt(3)/2;
x=[-2.5*a, -2*a, -a, -a/2, a/2, a, 2*a, 2.5*a, 2*a, 2.5*a, 2*a, a, a/2, -a/2, -a, -2*a, -2.5*a, -2*a, -a, -a/2, a/2, a, a/2, -a/2 ];
y=[b ,2*b ,2*b ,3*b ,3*b ,2*b ,2*b ,b ,0 ,-b ,-2*b ,-2*b ,-3*b ,-3*b ,-2*b ,-2*b ,-b ,0 ,0 ,b ,b ,0 ,-b ,-b ];
z = 0;
for i=1:numel(x)
    z = z + exp(sqrt(-1)*q*(x(i)*sin(alpha).*cos(phi) + y(i)*sin(alpha).*sin(phi)));
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation on why vectorization is not useful in this case! In the end I did as you said with non-anonymous functions and a for loop running over all q vectors. Plus I replaced one of the integrals by a naive Riemann sum (taking note of the error) to keep the total number of function calls down.